# Is it OK to use 6-7k texture map in Unity?

Tags: textures, performance, uv-mapping

I want to unwrap all my car into one texture (interier, wheels and e.t.c), so for better quality i need to use one big 7k texture. Is it OK or the better choice is to make smaller ones for groups ?

Comment: Many mobile devices won't allow textures over 2048x2048 or 4096x4096.

Answer (score 4):

Going by [WebGL Caps](http://webglstats.com/#highcharts-105) it looks like 4k textures are a very safe bet (which is why everyone is using them) but 8k textures still have a ways to go.

Ideally you'll want to have a 4k fallback option if your users don't support 8k textures.

That being said, your car shouldn't need an 8k texture, it's likely that your UV mapping could use some optimization. Make sure all your important surfaces are normalized and unimportant surfaces can be half the scale of the other islands, or even less.

Answer (score 3):

So long as the platform is able to handle the texture size for performance reasons it's better to use one big texture in virtually all cases instead of lots of little ones. So I would generally put the whole car on one texture. The only exception might be if there is a lot of chance for customization. IE change out the mags and tires, adding decals, stuff like that.

Comment: The whole game into one texture? :D

Comment: The platform is PC.

Comment: If you can get the whole game onto one texture sure. Most games put the whole GUI onto a single texture. Packing textures saves space and also renders faster. You could fit a whole atari game on one easily. But the cards limit the sizes a lot so that is not possible with any decent sized modern game obviously. But those limits get bigger and bigger all the time.

Comment: Yeah, a read about limits. It's not recommendet to use textures larger then 2048.

Comment: You might be able to go higher, too, if you don't care about old hardware. I think even my 10 year old card could go to 4096x4096. But it also gets hard to deal with those big files in photoshop.